# Applying hover over to a unordered list item if it belongs to two classes

Tags: css

I am trying to highlight the list items upon hover over except the first one.

This is the html:

```
  ...
  <ul class="topmenulist">
  <li><a href="#" class="active" >Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="notactive" >What we do</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="notactive" >Projects</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="notactive" >Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
  ...
```

This does NOT work:

```
  .notactive.topmenulist li:hover{ 
  background-color: #EAEAEA;
  }
```

This works BUT it also applies to the first one which I do not want:

```
  .topmenulist li:hover{ 
  background-color: #EAEAEA;
   }
```

Thanks

Comment: can you pass the classes `active` and `notactive` to the list-items?

Comment: otherwise it is the same question as: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.topmenulist li:hover a:not(.active) {
    background-color: #EAEAEA;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vWMFa/)

Or simpler:

```
.topmenulist li:hover a.notactive {
    background-color: #EAEAEA;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vWMFa/1/)

**EDIT:** If you want highlight all `li` that has `.noactive` you shoud apply `:hover` on `ul` (`.topmenulist`):

```
.topmenulist:hover li a.notactive {
    background-color: #EAEAEA;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vWMFa/2/)

Comment: you can also use: `a.notactive` as shown in the code above and this is not really an answer because he wants to highlight the list-items.

Comment: Thanks this works, but I was thinking how can I highlight the actual li tag instead of the a tag (like with ".topmenulist li:hover")?

Comment: @Crocodile - its impossible highlight parent of child ... you shoud move `active` and `noactive` classes to `li` and then you can: `.topmenulist:hover li.noactive`

Comment: Thanks @Shaddow, eventually I moved the .active class to the li tag and ended up using                     .topmenulist li:not(.active):hover      , but you lead me to the answer.